# Central Administration Forms Authentication On Premise and detect authentication provider

Tags: authentication, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I've been looking at Authentication providers for the Central Administration site for SharePoint 2016 on premise and don't see the option to enable forms authentication. I just wanted to check if this is correct and if this can be enabled by some other means ie the webconfig. I can see the option for new web applications but not the central administration.

Is it possible to determine through code which authentication has been set up on individual web applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an option. CA is a Classic Web Application which means you're limited to NTLM or Kerberos.

If you need an FBA-like experience, consider placing CA behind a pre-authentication reverse proxy, like Microsoft's Web Application Proxy + ADFS 3.0 or higher using a non-claims aware relying party.

Comment: Thanks, do you know if it's possible to detect the authentication provider for individual web applications?

Comment: `$wa = Get-SPWebApplication http://url; $wa.IisSettings[0]`. This will show you enabled providers.